# mystery metacafe thumb issue

Tags: vb.net, get

I'm having issue to retrive thumb from metacafe video id.
The problem is that even the url seems to be correct (after opening source html) but when we change the new ID in the same URL it will return 400 error page.
Here is the working url:
http://cdn.mcstatic.com/contents/videos_screenshots/11827000/11827430/preview.jpg

Here is not working url:
http://cdn.mcstatic.com/contents/videos_screenshots/11826998/11826998/preview.jpg

Seems like really crazy that even the wrong URL contains same direct thumb link but when type it will get 404 not found.

I hope someone could solve this mystery.

```
Public Sub getThumb()
        Dim thumbURL As String = "http://cdn.mcstatic.com/contents/videos_screenshots/"
        Dim videoID As String = "1827000"

        PreviewBox.ImageLocation = (thumbURL + videoID + "/" + videoID + "/preview.jpg")

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know where these URL come from, but the path ID you're using here: `1827000`, is not the same as the one shown in the URL: `11827000`. You have, apparently, one *number* less in your string.

Comment: hey Jim thx for reply BUT check the url and see video ID is "11827726" on the video player we can see the picture url if you type: http://www.metacafe.com/embed/11827726/a-really-fishy-fight-back/ and see source page under <script> . It is not all, well the source page show this url for pic: http:\/\/cdn.mcstatic.com\/contents\/videos_screenshots\/11827000\/11827726\/preview.jpg BUT why it doesnt have same ID trwice like some other URL? This is why I cant scrape the thumb because the other videos sometimes have 2 ID in the thumb url, thats why "mystery" thx for help

Comment: You don't need to care about this. The thumb image is contained in a `DIV` element: `<div class="poster" style="background-image: url("http://cdn.mcstatic.com/contents/videos_screenshots/11827000/11827726/830x467/1.jpg")></div>`. You just need to use `GetElementsByTagName("DIV")`, filtering the element by class name: `.GetAttribute("className") = "poster")`. Get the `Element.Style` string and extract the Http address of the thumb image. The `Dim videoID As String = "1827000"` still refers to the wrong number.

Comment: To sum of it up is, you can't determine beforehand which is the preview image just looking at the video ID. The thumb sub-ID can be the same or anthing else.

Comment: so what do you suggest Jimi? I already sent them email support as they do not have API and it is like 5 days now and seems like they dont care it is very sad and unbelievable situation as at least they could answer me, so thats why Im looking here for help but looks like I will soon give up and focus on other project I have in mind, but still if you have any suggestion I would appreciate.

Comment: I have already described this. Get the Html page that contains the video, extract the preview link (inside the `DIV` with `className` `"poster"`), download the Bitmap and use it where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

After some external help from someone I get this done.
I hope it will help someone.

```
Public Sub getThumb()
        Dim thumbURL As String = "http://cdn.mcstatic.com/contents/videos_screenshots/"
        Dim videoID As String = "1827000"

        PreviewBox.ImageLocation = (thumbURL + videoID.Remove(videoID.Length - 3) + "000/" + videoID + "/preview.jpg")
End Sub
```